# Not Backing Up Files That Don't Change In A WordPress Install

Tags: wordpress, database-backup, backup

I have a WordPress install and I'm wonder what is generally best practice when it comes to back up. I'm asking here instead of WordPress.stackexchange as this question is not only a WordPress question but a general backup question.

Is it okay to **NOT** Backup files that won't change. For example in my install I have files such as the theme and plugin directories which won't change and I'll have a copy of these files in there original state. My thinking is then that they shouldn't need to be backed up as they can just be restored at any point.

Is this good logic? Or is it better to back up everything on the server?

*Note: I'm not talking about the database as this sill be backed up weekly (small site)*

Comment: If you have a copy of the files in the original state, that _is_ a backup.

Answer (score 1):

Depending if you follow Wordpress's best practices, most of the content (from a file perspective) you are worried about is in the 'wp-content' directory. That plus your 'wp-config.php' would comprise a minimal backup.Yes, you can get by with only backing up the 'unique' files.

However, most installations I've seen have various other files (robots.txt, favicon.ico, Google Analytics verification files, etc). The actual Wordpress files you are excluding are only a couple MB. Your uploads are usually considerably larger. I don't think you are saving much by excluding the Wordpress core files, and you are making it harder to restore to a point in time.